# Get Microsoft Teams/Graph user status message via API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

It looks like you can get a user's **presence** via API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. But I can't find any way to get the Teams status itself, specifically this thing:

[image: user status message in teams]

I've seen various people asking about it in other forums, I assume it doesn't exist yet but maybe somebody knows how, perhaps there's an undocumented way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Currently we do not have any Graph API to get the status set in Teams.

You can raise a user voice here: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new

Comment: Created one here https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/875338af-0891-ec11-a81b-000d3ae26307

Comment: RIP user voice...
There is a Microsoft 365 Developer Platform feedback item for this here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/include-teams-status-in-graph-presence-api/idi-p/2718878

Comment: looks like they added this as a beta feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-setstatusmessage?view=graph-rest-beta&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http